# CodeIgniter extending controller using composer not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, optimization, composer-php, spl-autoload-register

I am trying extending CodeIgniter controller in my application using composer but it's not working.

This give me

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\ci-dev\application\core\MY_Controller.php on line 11
```

**i knew that if i add spl_autoload_register in my config.php then it is work but i want to use composer.**

here is my all set up.

i create MY_Controller in my **application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

after this i add admin controller in **application/libraries/Admin_Controller.php**

```
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and front-end controller in **application/libraries/Frontend_Controller.php**

```
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

This is my default controller index call

```
class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

i set up my composer like this in config.php

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'../vendor/autoload.php';
```

and composer.json file like this

```
"autoload": {
      "files" : [
        "application/core/MY_Controller.php",
        "application/libraries/Admin_Controller.php",
        "application/libraries/Frontend_Controller.php"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Is good path? `FCPATH` is `ci-dev`, and you are going in directory up with `$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: i moved `index.php` file in `public_html` in `ci-dev` folder and my composer `vendor` folder in `ci-dev` folder

Comment: CI_Controller not found means other classes are found. Leave same configuration, but extend Welcome class with CI_Controller to see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter loads `CI_Controller` *after* your vendor/autoload.php file, and since you're listing them under the "files" option in your composer.json, they're included *immediately* as opposed to right when you need them.

That's not only what causes the error, but also beats the entire purpose of using an autoloader - if you'd be explicitly listing the includes, you might as well just `require_once` them.

What's common in CI, is to `require` or even directly declare your multiple base controller classes from inside MY_Controller.php - then you know they'll be available exactly when you need them.

But if you insist on loading them through Composer, there's a work-around - list system/core/Controller.php under the autoloaded files as well.